# Application gets very slow - Azure Web App

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I have a Web site deployed on Azure Web App. My web site gets very slow at times. This behavior is random.

On checking IIS Logs during the period of slowness, I found few requests coming in where the Client IP Address is blank (It shows "-").
The response time of these requests runs into minutes and finally they result into HTTP 500 error. This happens only for the requests where c-ip is blank.

All other requests that have a Client-IP address are processed successfully. But because of the bad requests my application becomes very slow. I have to restart my Web App to resolve this issue.

What could be the possible reason behind these requests having a blank Client IP Address ? Could this be a malicious attack on the web site ?

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say. Could you add Application Insights service to your project? It allows you to see what is going on before and after 5 minutes of "this" request. The second reason can be the mode of your Azure Web App - is it free or shared or standard?

After AI added, you could share some more insights, because it is important to know what is that request about, not just the fact that it was processed.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-start-monitoring-app-health-usage/